# Sidebar folder shortcuts all disappeared after update

Tags: finder

I've just updated from 10.10.1 to 10.10.3 and now all of the folder shortcuts on my sidebar have disappeared, e.g., 'Desktop', 'Downloads'. Does anyone know how to fix it?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: they are usually in favorites. You can manually drag them. So navigate to`/` and then put applications in favorites. Then `/Users/yourname/` and drag Desktop manually

Comment: @TheBro21 I'm not very keen on recreating each one by one since there were heaps. I wonder if there's a way to restore them.

Comment: I. think Tetsujin has answered your question :)

Comment: Newer solution at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406722/what-casues-macos-sidebar-to-drop-favorites-shortcuts-to-linked-files-directo/406768#406768

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try Finder prefs > Sidebar -  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>,</kbd>  - they may just have become unchecked…

[image]

Any that are still missing after that - previous customer entries etc, can be restored by selecting the appropriate drive/folder/app in any Finder window & hitting  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>/</kbd>  or File Menu > Add to Sidebar

Perhaps Time Machine would have an older version?
The prefs are at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist`
If you navigate there then enter Time Machine, it may have an older version you could recover

Comment: Well, I guess they're all gone..! Oh well..

Comment: Maybe Time Machine… adding new paragraph...

Comment: My shortcut folders were *still checked*, but unchecking and rechecking them caused Finder to suddenly show them again.

Comment: `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` does not exist for me on Ventura

Comment: @derpedy-doo -  Well done for being first to spot the 'deliberate error', 8 years after this answer was posted ;) It is, of course, at `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` not `/Library/…` I cannot attest to its continuing presence 8 years after the fact.

Comment: That file also does not exist. For newer macOS (Ventura at least), this is the solution now: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/406768

Answer (score 6):

I was able to use time machine and my sidebar got completely restored.

1. Navigate here

~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist

1. Selected that file
2. From the time machine menu select "Enter Time Machine"
3. Time machine will take you right to the file you highlighted. The only thing it will be TODAY'S version of that file.
4. Using the meter on the right side of the screen, select a date PRIOR to the problem. Give it time. It has to search backwards.
5. Once it brings you to the file (you may have to scroll down to find it). Select that file ONLY and hit restore. It will ask you for permission to restore. Have it replace the current file.
6. Once it's done, restart your machine.
7. And once you restart, your side bar should return!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Great first answer.

Comment: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` does not exist for me on Ventura

Answer (score 0):

The date on my `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist` file is from May 2019. Years old. Yet once again Finder dropped all my lovingly created shortcuts in sidebar. So I cannot restore.

Also, when i add new aliases to sidebar the file does not update… so how can I save this file for restoration at a later date. I think I'm going to have to Applescript this SOAB to save a plist file and restore a plist file with the locations and then recreate the sidebar links one by one. Tedious in the extreme. Apple, if you are reading this, this has been a known issue for a decade. Get it together please.