# What casues macOS sidebar to drop "favorites" (shortcuts to linked files/directories), other than macOS updates? How to prevent?

Tags: macos, finder, applescript, shortcut, symlink

Every month or so my Macs drops all the favorites I have in the Finder windows (which also appear in Save/Open system dialogue windows). I takes time to redo them, and it is frustrating.

I know that there are questions here and on other forums about this happening after macOS updates, but I find it happens without warning -- even without doing a User logout and login it can happen, especially links to pCloud files (which uses a virtual drive system extensions.) Links to directories on external and ***mounted*** volumes disappear as well!

I've tried using symlinks in Terminal and they suffer the same fate. The only other thing I can think of is an Applescript routine to save the aliases to a list in a file and another routine to reinstall the links as "Favorites".

This has occurred in many past versions of macOS for as long as I can remember.  My Mac is currently on Mojave (internal boot partition) and Catalina (external drive boot partition.)

Does anybody have any viable solutions and/or remedies I should consider?

Comment: wide_eyed_pupil, Please do not let the unwarranted down-vote on my answer keep you from considering it. It is a valid and workable solution to your issue even though someone has down-voted it for no litigate reason!

Comment: I was doing some testing on this as I have a few favorites that haven't "fallen off" the sidebar as they are volumes on my internal drive.  However, I have had NFS, SMB and external drive mounts disappear from favorites because they were removable.  I found that if the connection was broken (the machine with the NFS share went down, for example) the favorite would disappear.  Is it possible that this is the case?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what's causing you to loose the customizations you've made to *items* under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder** or how to prevent it, however here is a backup and restore solution for when it does happen. This should certainly be easier then manually having to restore all the lost *items* under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder**.

At one time, *items* under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder** were stored in the **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.finder.plist** *file* and then the **~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.sidebarlists.plist** *file*.

However, they are now stored in:

```bash
~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2
```

Which version of **macOS** it was changed to the later I'm not sure, however certainly in **macOS Mojave** and later it is in **com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2** *file*.

In at least **macOS Mojave** and later, to backup this *file* after the *items* you always want to be under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder**, to then later restore as needed, first do the following in **Terminal**:

```bash
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/
cp com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2 com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2.Custom
```

With that done, if and when the *items* under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder** get reset and your customizations are lost, then do the following to restore them:

In **Terminal**:

```bash
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist/
cp com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2.Custom com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems.sfl2
```

Then immediately press **⇧⌘Q** and then **Enter** to **Log Out**.

Once the *log out* is complete, you can *log in* and the **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder** will be back to your customized settings.

---

**Note:** You may have to give **Full Disk Access** to **Terminal** in **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** in order to run the aforementioned *commands*.

Comment: This answer certainly provides a method to backup and restore _items_ under **Favorites** in the **Sidebar** of **Finder**! So, to whomever downvoted this answer, please share the reason why, so it can be improved if it's missing something.

Comment: @wide_eyed_pupil, If my answer worked for you I'd appreciate if you'd upvote it and or make it as the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: Works on Ventura and saved my butt, thanks. (I restored an old copy of this file from Time Machine.)